# WebApi 2.0 - ApiControllers in another assembly fail to map if runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a WebApi2 application that implements a few ApiControllers.

The same application references an assembly that implements a few more.

All those controllers utilize Attribute Routing, like so:

```
[RoutePrefix("sample1.endpoint")]
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage WebApiTest()
```

If I define `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` at `web.config`, the application works flawlessly - but I want to get rid of this catch-all situation.

If I instead set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to "false", only my local ApiControllers are mapped.

What (probably obvious) part am I missing?